# How to reference a custom class library in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created a windows phone class library, I need to add this library as a reference to my application. How do I do this?

Comment: The same problem is there
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599293/how-to-add-external-non-windows-phone-class-library-project-reference-to-a-windo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as a normal project/class library - right click on the project in solution explorer, select add reference. If the project is also in the current solution, choose it from the projects tab.

Comment: Project is not in the current solution, so I have to use browse tab right?. If I use browse tab which file do I need to select and add.

Comment: @saikamesh if it's not in the solution, browse to the built DLL (as an aside, I would recommend putting the other project into the solution, to ease debugging later on)

Comment: Thanks, I put the class library project into my application's solution and now it has started showing up in the projects tab itself. If I do not put the class library in the same solution, where can I select the DLL from?(means under which folder in the class library project, the DLL can be found)

Comment: @saikamesh the exact path that the built assembly goes to is configurable in the project settings, so that isn't something that can be answered without access to the source - it would also differ by configuration.

Comment: This throws an error for me.  Anyone else here get "Unable to add the selected project reference. The project reference must be another Silverlight for Windows Phone project that is the same or lower version"?

Comment: @Milimetric sounds like your other class library isn't compiled against Windows Phone

Comment: Found what the problem was that was giving me the error message above: I was using the wrong version of .net when compiling my other class.