# How to add external non windows phone class library project reference to a windows phone project?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, windows-phone-7

Hi there I am new to the windows phone development and I am trying to build a data driven application in which I have Created my BLL and EL and DAL ,which are all of windows phone class library type project.
I have also an extra project of type class library in my solution in which I have added the Reference to "MyGeneration.dOOdads.dll" file .
Now I want this project to be referenced in the windows phone app project.But when I try to add a reference ,The VS 2010 says...***."Unable to add the selected project refernce.The project reference must be another silver light for windows phone project that is the same or the lower version "***.
.
.
.
Kindly help me in this scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can't and won't work. The phone runtime only has access to a timy subset (well, sort-of) of the full .NET libraries, so any non-phone-7 library is extremely unlikely to operate at all. To stop this surprising people, only libraries built against that runtime are allowed to be referenced.

If possible, create a new project with the same c# files, targeting the phone 7 framework. Now reference this project. It is quite likely that some bits will fail to compile (demonstrating the fact that it also wouldn't have run), which can be rectified in a number if ways (`#if` blocks, alternative `.cs` files, etc).

You might also have some luck by making the existing project a "portable class library" - this, however, is the most restrictive subset of *all* the common frameworks, and is even less likely to still compile (without changes).

> Using the Portable Class Library project, you can build portable assemblies that work without modification on the .NET Framework, Silverlight, Windows Phone 7, or Xbox 360 platforms.

(from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx))

Comment: Thanks so much Marc Gravell. But could you please provide some more details on Portable Class Library projects and how to add some other projects references in these kinda libraries.
Thanks

Comment: @SoftBuildersPk they are simply a restricted library that limits itself to the common intersection of the others mentioned. A portable class library can only reference things in the portable framework :) to create such, first install the Portable Library Tools pack for VS010 from MSDN (it is inbuilt into VS 11). You might need to recreate the csproj as a "Portable Class Library", but after that, you should be able to reference it from multiple project types.

Comment: Not all of these assemblies are supported on all platforms. In a Portable Class Library project, you specify the platforms you want to target, and **only the supported assemblies for those platforms are referenced in your project**. If you try to reference an assembly that is not supported for the platforms you have targeted, Visual Studio warns you of the incompatibility.**(MSDN)**

That is what I know because it makes sense as I am inserting the reference of a non WP7 class library to a WP7 project.
Isn't  there any way around to do the thing which I am wondering???? ;)
Thanks

Comment: @SoftBuildersPk what is the thing you are trying to reference from the PCL?

Comment: A non windows phone class library i.e. a simple class library that can be added in any ASP.NET site project.

Comment: @SoftBuildersPk you seem to be missing the point. If you want to reference it from multiple platforms, you need to create it as a PCL (and limit the library to what the PCL can access, which is: not a lot, really). If you don't want to do that, you are going to need completely separate builds per platform. No, you cannot reference a regular "full .NET" assembly from WP7.

Comment: Sir. I have only one platform i.e. Windows phone .ok.now  What my problem is I need a way out to add a reference to **"MyGeneration.dOOdads.dll"** which comes from MyGeneration.dOOdads code generator.(which is of course is not a WP7 dll file). So from your last comment " No, you cannot reference a regular "full .NET" assembly from WP7" Should I discard this approach and write my own custom Libraries.

Thank you soooooooooooooo much for your concern :)

Comment: @SoftBuildersPk k; does MyGeneration generate as c#? or as a dll? If c#, just change the target platform. If a dll, then it depends on what the dll does internally. You *might* (if it is important enough to try) be able to re-target the dll and all the references via [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil). What tool generated the dll? Cross-framework generators is complex, but is an area I am familiar with (see http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html). But it all hinges on "what created that dll, and how?"

Comment: @SoftBuildersPk of course, if the dll does things that **aren't supported / available** on WP7, then: it cannot be done.